# how to fetch and display the data one by one by clicking next button

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a quiz management system and need to fetch the data from the database and displaying the data one by one on clicking next button.

I have used ajax to insert data into database after clicking next button  by using file read and write function.

I am hoping for a better and efficient solution for my problem.

```
 <?php
    $host="localhost";
    $user="root";
    $pass="";
    $con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass);//connect to database;
    mysqli_select_db($con,'*****');
    // Create connection
    //$conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass);
    ?>

    <html>
    <head>
      <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
      <!--Import materialize.css-->
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
      <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
      <style>
         nav {
                background-color: #2196F3 !important;
             }
             .second {

                background-color: #61BAE4 !important;
                height:45px;
             }

             .logo {
                    display: inline-block;
                    height: 100%;
                }

             .logo>img {
                    vertical-align: middle
                    padding-bottom: 10px;
                }

                @media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {


                @media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {

                 .card-panel{
                     width:280px !important;
                 }
                 nav{
                     width:300px !important;
                 }

      </style>
    </head>

    <body style="background-color:  #969696;">   
     <div class="row">


            <nav>
                    <div class="nav-wrapper">
                      <a href="#!" class="brand-logo logo"><img width="60" height="60" src="https://www.timefortest.com/images/logo1.png" alt=""><span>IBPS Portal</span></a>
                      <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
                      <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                        <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Candidates</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Add Question</a></li>
                        <li><a id="logout" href="logout">Logout</a></li>
                        <li><a id="logout" href="logout"><i class="material-icons">lock_outline</i></a></li>
                      </ul>
                     <!--<ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
                        <li><a href="sass.html">Dashboard</a></li>
                        <li><a href="badges.html">Candidates</a></li>
                        <li><a href="collapsible.html">Add Question</a></li>
                        <li><a id="logout" href="logout">Logout</a></li>
                        <li><a href="sass.html"><i class="material-icons">lock_outline</i></a></li>

                      </ul>-->
                    </div>
            </nav>
            </div>
    <!--<nav class="second">
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <div class="col s12">
        <a href="#!" class="breadcrumb">Dashboard</a>
        <a href="#!" class="breadcrumb">Add Questions</a>
        <a href="#!" class="breadcrumb">Multiple Choice</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    </nav>-->
    <?php $var=0;?><?php


    //<div id="response">
    ?><form method="POST" action="submitanswer.php" id="answerdata">
    <?php
    $myfile = fopen("hitcount.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $fh=fread($myfile,filesize("hitcount.txt"));
    fclose($myfile);
            $sql="SELECT description,question,choiceA,choiceB,choiceC,choiceD,choiceE,msqid FROM master_question where msqid=$fh";
        if($r=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
        {
            while($result= $r->fetch_row())
            {



    ?> 
    <div class="col s12 m12"style="background-color:Orange;">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col s6 m6">

                <h4 style="color:white;">DESCRIPTION</h4>
                <div class="card horizontal" style="height:500px;background-color:white;">  

                  <div class="card-stacked">
                    <div class="card-content">
                      <h5> <?php echo $result[0]?> </h4>
                    </div>
                    </div>

                  </div>
                </div>
    <div class="col s6 m6">
                <h4 style="color:white;">QUESTION</h4>
                <div class="card horizontal"style="height:500px;background-color:white;">

                  <div class="card-stacked">
                    <div class="card-content">
                      <h5><?php echo $result[1]?></h4>

                      </br />

                       <div class="card-stacked"style="padding-top:40px;">
                        <div class="card-content">

                        <input type="hidden" name="msqid" value="<?php echo $result[7]?>"/> 
                        <p>
                          <input type="radio" name="group" id="test1" name="test1" value="<?php echo $result[1]?>" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
                          <label for="test1"><Strong> <?php echo $result[2]?></strong></label>

                        </p>
                        <br />
                        <p>
                          <input type="radio" name="group" id="test2" name="test2" value="<?php echo $result[2]?>" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
                          <label for="test2"><Strong><?php echo $result[3]?></strong></label>

                        </p>
                        <br />
                        <p>
                          <input type="radio" name="group" id="test3" name="test3" value="<?php echo $result[3]?>" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
                          <label for="test3"><Strong><?php echo $result[4]?></strong></label>

                        </p>
                        <br />
                        <p>
                          <input type="radio" name="group" id="test4" name="test4" value="<?php echo $result[4]?>" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
                          <label for="test4"><Strong><?php echo $result[5]?></strong></label>

                        </p>
                        <br />
                        <p>
                          <input type="radio" name="group" id="test5" name="test5" value="<?php echo $result[5]?>" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
                          <label for="test5"><Strong><?php echo $result[6]?></strong></label>

                        </p>

                      </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                  </div>
                </div>

    </div>
    </div>

            <?php } }  ?>
               <div class="col s12 m12">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col s6 m6">
                <center>
                <input type='button'value='back' class="btn" onclick="document.location.href='decrement.php';"/>
               </center>

                </div>
                <div class="col s6 m6 offset-s3">
                <center>
                <button type="submit" id="submcq" value="Submit" name="Snext" class="btn btn-success">Next</button></center>    
                </center>

                </div>
                </div>
                </div>


    </div>
    </form>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script> 
      $(".button-collapse").sideNav();<!--nav jquery starts-->
        $(document).ready(function() {
                                    Materialize.updateTextFields();
                                    $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
                                    $('select').material_select();
                                    });
            </script>
    <script>    
    function copy() {
    document.getElementById("label").innerHTML = document.getElementById("mySelect").value
    }<!--to label the selected value-->     
     $(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').material_select();
    });   </script>

    <script><!--ajax function to insert answer in answer table-->
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("answerdata").on('submit',(function (e){
      e.preventDefault();

       $.ajax({
           type:'POST',
           url:'submitanswer.php',
           data:$('#answerdata').serialize(),
           contentType:true,
           cache:true,
           processData:true,
          success:function(){
            alert("worked");
        }
       });

    }));


    return false;
    });


    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Insert page:

```
    <?php
$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$pass="";
$con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass);//connect to database;
mysqli_select_db($con,'******');
?>
<?php

   if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

       $msqid=$_POST['msqid'];
       $answer=$_POST['group'];

     $sql="INSERT INTO review(question_attend,Question_id,answerA,answerB,answerC,answerD,answerE)VALUES('','$msqid','$answer','','','','')";
     $query= mysqli_query($con,$sql);
          if($query)
          {
              echo "success";


             $fp = fopen('hitcount.txt', 'c+');
                flock($fp, LOCK_EX);

                $count = (int)fread($fp, filesize('hitcount.txt'));
                ftruncate($fp, 0);
                fseek($fp, 0);
                fwrite($fp, $count + 1);

                flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
                fclose($fp);
              header("Location: newfetch.php"); 


          }
          else
          {
              echo mysqli_error;
          }

   }
?>
```

Comment: What is the expected situation and actual situation? If the code works, what do you want to achieve? Asking for a "better way" is off topic at SO

Comment: I have achieved the issue by using a text file which contain a single numerical value which will get incremented when clicking the Next button based on the incremented value next question will be fetched and displayed in the page. If i want to run the test again we have to reset the value of the text file manually.  So am looking for a better solution for this issue

Comment: There is far too much code in your question. You need to post a [mcve]

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL.

Comment: Also, **never** get your web app to login to the database as root. Root can do whatever it likes,
so on top of the SQL injection vulnerabilities
this just leaves your database an open book for hackers.
Instead create a separate user account specifically for this application which has only the permissions it actually _needs_ in order to work properly.

Comment: Anyway..." If i want to run the test again we have to reset the value of the text file manually. ". Personally I'd have used the Session to store such a value, since it relates to that specific user's use of the system, and each user could be on a different page. Then to start the test again you just have to close the browser and re-open it, to get a new session.

Comment: Okay sir Is there any way for declaring a global variable common for two different php page

Comment: storing the info in the Session is one good way. Or declare a variable in a 3rd PHP file and include that file at the top of both the other files.

Comment: Am working on it sir on declaring a variable in 3rd php file